# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

Quando executo um script Python ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flemos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flemos\Desktop\OptimalRoadTripHtmlSaveAndDisplay.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\flemos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Comment: Qual o código das linhas 7 e 13 do `__init__.py`? Pode editar sua pergunta?

Comment: Como você instalou o **Pandas**? Às vezes é meio chatinho de instalar algumas dessas bibliotecas de processamento de dados no Windows. Eu recomendaria instalar elas já pré-compiladas, [baixando daqui](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) a versão correta (32 vs 64 bits). Depois instala com `pip install pandas‑0.17.0‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl`